# PDF viewer with dual page option?

Tags: viewers

I wonder if there is a viewer, or a whole TeX package allowing me to display two pages side by side. I have two big monitors and I cannot use them effectively now. PCTEX comes close but not quite - it has a DVI viewer, which creates a lot of problems with embedded figures. I have Texworks and Texstudio installed, and they cannot do that.

I am running Win 7.

Comment: ....SumatraPDF?

Comment: adobe acrobat can show two pages side by side

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but it is probably the worst viewer to work with TeX...

Comment: @karlkoeller well true in that it locks the pdf for writing but still it answers the question:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right, but also forget about synctexing with it

Answer (score 8):

Apart from the fact that I use SumatraPDF and I'm completely satisfied with it (I suggest it to you, it has the feature you've mentioned and many others), TeXMaker built-in viewer supports this feature, if you like this feature to be built-in.

Note that TeXMaker is not much different from TeXStudio, which is a fork of it.

To enable this feature in TeXMaker, just click on the 'eye' button and select 'Two Pages' as you can see in the following image. That's it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try Sumatra. Can it be integrated with some tex package as well as the other viewers - jump from source to PDF and back? I will try TexStudio as well.

Comment: I think it is the best viewer when it comes to forward and inverse search. If for 'tex package' you mean tex editor, the answer is yes, see [its tag](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/sumatrapdf/info). PS: I use WinEdt 8 + SumatraPDF 2.3 and they work perfectly together

Comment: How do I integrate SumatraPDF with MikTeX (sync, etc.)?

Comment: This is done with the editor you are using. What editor are you going to use?

Comment: Say, the one coming with TexStudio or Texworks.

Comment: I managed to make SumatraPDF open with TexStudio. But I cannot do the synchronization.

Comment: Texmaker works, kinda. With the viewer in external mode does not; and jumping from tex to pdf is Ctrl-space, back is Ctrl-click. Very inconvenient. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: The problem that I am having with TeMaker's two-page views is that it is showing left pages on the right side, and right pages on the left side.  Is there a fix for this in settings somewhere ?  I have two-page artwork that I'd like to view how the seam relates to the overall image.

Comment: why does 2-page-viewing not place the first page on the right side for BOOKS ?  I am doing  book that has several two-paged graphics throughout.  Opting for 2-page layout does me no good in these cases ... is there a setting for this somewhere. for texmaker ?

Answer (score 1):

Since Sumatra has already been suggested by KarlKoeller, I would like to suggest Adobe Reader as well.

You can set it to display two pages as a book by setting two things:

1. View/Page Display/Two Page view
2. View/Page Display/Show Cover page in two page view.

Comment: with `hyperref` it is possible to force displaying a two side layout: `\hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=TwoPageRight}` (It works with Adobe Reader only)

Answer (score 1):

evince is the default PDF viewer in GNOME and has also a two side option

Answer (score 1):

In TeXStudio viewer: In View > Grid unselect "Single Page Step" and click on 2x1.